# Multiple patterns in Makefile

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I am using makefiles to manage dependencies in computational experiments. It would very often be useful to have targets with multiple patterns.

For example, I may have some conditions, say A and B, and different folds (i.e. splits of data) of a cross-validation experiment, say 1 through 10.

Currently I just copy and paste the same commands for A and B, and pattern-match on the folds, but if there are more than two conditions it quickly becomes a maintenance problem.

```
output-%.A: input-%
run A input-$* output-$*.A

output-%.B: input-%
run B input-$* output-$*.B
```

Is there a better way of doing this in makefile? 
If not, what other tool would solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One drawback of Make is that it doesn't handle wildcards well. But there is a way to minimize the redundancy in this makefile.

First, let's use [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to clean up the rules a little bit:

```
output-%.A: input-%
    run A $< $@

output-%.B: input-%
    run B $< $@
```

Then we define a rule template, use [`call`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function) to evaluate it for A and for B, and [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) to interpret those things as actual rules:

```
define fold-rule
output-%.$(1): input-%
        @echo run $(1) $$< $$@     # <-- note the doubled '$'
endef

$(eval $(call fold-rule,A))
$(eval $(call fold-rule,B))
```

Finally we put the conditions in a variable, and iterate using [`foreach`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function):

```
CONDITIONS := A B

define fold-rule
output-%.$(1): input-%
        @echo run $(1) $$< $$@
endef

$(foreach x, $(CONDITIONS), $(eval $(call fold-rule,$(x))))
```

Now when you want to add a new condition, just modify the first line.

It isn't pretty, but it works.

Comment: I disagree that "it isn't pretty".  It is exactly the right thing to do and is as pretty as it is going to get.

Comment: Thanks for both good answers. This one is plain make so I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a few features of [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/), like using variable as macro-functions, and early evalution with `$[]` it is easy:

```
define runner
output-%.$1: input-%
    run $1 $$(input) $$(output)
enddef

$[runner A]
$[runner B]
$[runner C]
```

If you want to create a lot of rules, this may still be too verbose.  Problem with the `foreach` function is that it joins the results with a space.  So to separate the rules, you can put a dummy empty expression the last line:

```
define runner
output-%.$1: input-%
    run $1 $$(input) $$(output)
$()
enddef

$[foreach type,D E F,$[runner $[type]]]
```